# Why are some questions on the homepage beige?

Tags: discussion

This is just out of curiosity more than anything, but on the homepage (top questions - interesting), some of them are beige, while others are white. I'm sure there is a reason for this, but I can't see to find it. :)

Comment: See [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) In short, they have one of your favorite tags.

Comment: It's a horrible colour.  SO site devs have no artistic soul :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creme colored, "highlighted" questions contain one of your interesting/favorite tags.

Comment: good to know...I usually don't even look at the ones that are creme colored thinking it meant something else that pertained to me.